# how can we add background images to FullModeItemTemplate in listpicker wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

Is there any way to add backbround image to `FullModeItemTemplate` in `ListPicker`
i want to implement this in my app

my xaml code is:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker1" Grid.Row="0" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FullModeHeader="Select City" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Header="Select City">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cities}" Width="250" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cities}" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="44"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add a background image to each item in the list or a background image of the FullMode page?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of the ListPickerPage.xaml file from the Windows Phone Toolkit in your aplication, set the background and set tge PickerPageUri property to the new page. For example;

```
<toolkit:ListPicker 
   x:Name="ListPicker"
   ...
   PickerPageUri="/Controls/ListPickerPage.xaml"
/>
```